# Using accepts_nested_attributes_for to create a double nested record with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 5 and I'm having trouble creating a doubly nested record using accepts_nested_attributes_for. I have Models that looks like this:

```
Class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :terms, inverse_of: :quote
  has_many :mileages, inverse_of: :quote
end

Class Term < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quote, optional: true
end

Class Mileage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quote, optional: true
end

Class Residual < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :term, optional: true
  belongs_to :mileage, optional: true
end
```

And I am trying to use accepts_nested_attributes_for to create a Residual record when creating a new Quote. It is working fine for Term and Mileage, and even Rebate and MoneyFactor which is nested under Term (I am leaving those out because they are working fine),
but I am having difficulty when trying to create a Residual because it belongs to two different models that belongs to Quote. I've read many posts about nested_attributes_for but none seem to deal with this specific situation.

My QuotesController create action:

```
  def create
    @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)
    @quote.user_id = current_user.id

    if @quote.save
      @quotes = current_user.quotes.includes(:terms, :rebates, 
       :money_factors, :residuals, :mileages)
       render :index
    else
     render json: @quote, status: 422
    end
  end
```

Here are the strong params in my Quotes controller:

```
  def quote_params
    params.require(:quote).permit(:user_id, :lead_id, :year, :make, 
     :make_id, :model, :model_id, :trim, :trim_id, :title, :msrp, :sell_price, :profit, :customer_cash, :bank_fee_plan,
  :registration_plan, :smog_plan, :misc_fee_plan, :rebate_tax_plan, :doc_fee_plan,
  :down_payment, :drive_off, :monthly_payment, :tax, :bank_fee, :registration, :doc_fee, :smog,
  :misc_fee, :rebate_tax,

  mileages_attributes: [:id, :quote_id, :mileage,
    residual_attributes: [:id, :term_id, :mileage_id, :residual]
  ],
  terms_attributes: [
    :id,
    :months,
    rebates_attributes: [:id, :term_id, :amount],
    money_factors_attributes: [:id, :term_id, :money_factor],
    residuals_attributes: [:id, :term_id, :mileage_id, :residual]
  ]
)
  end
```

I am using React with Redux on the front end so this is what my view looks like :

```
const quote = merge({}, this.state, {
  terms_attributes: [{
    months: this.state.months,
    rebates_attributes: [{ amount: this.state.rebate }],
    money_factors_attributes: [{ money_factor: this.state.money_factor }],
    residuals_attributes: [{ residual: this.state.residual }]
  }],
  mileages_attributes: [{ mileage: this.state.mileage, residuals_attributes: [{ residual: this.state.residual }] }],
});
```

here are my full Quote, Term, Mileage, and Residual models:

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord

 validates :user_id, presence: true

 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :lead, optional: true

 has_many :mileages, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :quote

 has_many :terms, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :quote

 has_many :rebates,
  through: :terms,
  source: :rebates

 has_many :money_factors,
  through: :terms,
  source: :money_factors

 has_many :residuals,
  through: :mileages,
  source: :residuals

 has_many :residuals,
  through: :terms,
  source: :residuals


 accepts_nested_attributes_for :mileages, :terms, allow_destroy: true

end

class Term < ApplicationRecord

 validates :months, presence: true

 belongs_to :quote, optional: true

 has_many :rebates, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :money_factors, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :residuals, dependent: :destroy

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :rebates, :money_factors, :residuals, 
allow_destroy: true

end

class Mileage < ApplicationRecord

 validates :mileage, presence: true

 belongs_to :quote, optional: true

 has_many :residuals, dependent: :destroy

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :residuals, allow_destroy: true
end

class Residual < ApplicationRecord

 validates :residual, presence: true

 belongs_to :term, optional: true
 belongs_to :mileage, optional: true
end
```

Comment: Your `Term` and `Mileage` models also need associations to the `Residual` model if you want to use deeply-nested attributes.

Comment: can u add your controller and view code?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `#accepts_nested_attributes_for`. You've got two options here: set up two one-to-many relationship or use polymorphic. Assuming Residual already has `term_id` and `mileage_id` columns, you can add `has_many :residuals` in `Term` and `Mileage`.

Polymorphic:
This enables you to set up one interface for `Residual` to work with any number of models.

```
Class Term < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quote, optional: true
  has_many: residuals, as: :residualable 
end

Class Mileage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quote, optional: true
  has_many: residuals, as: :residualable
end

Class Residual < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :residualable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end
```

Make sure you have `residualable_id` and `residualable_type` columns in your Residuals table.

Comment: So I have tried your first approach, I gave both Term and Mileage a has_many relationship to Residual, but when I try to save to the db I get a  " null value in column "mileage_id" violates not-null constraint". The reason for this I believe is that the residual record being created when nested under Term doesn't know about the Mileage record and therefore doesn't have its ID.

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, when using polymorphic associations each Residual will only be assigned to either a Mileage or a Term, but in my case a Residual always has both a specific Mileage and Term.

Comment: You're right polymorphic doesn't work here if you want your model to belong to multiple models. You just have to use multiple `belongs_to` instead. About your error, can you show your form and controller?